# How can I successfully glaze asparagus?

Tags: vegetables, glaze, asparagus

I've tried making [this recipe](http://www.myrecipes.com/recipe/apricot-glazed-roasted-asparagus) a few times, and the glaze never really sticks to the asparagus.  I feel like there should be a better technique for getting glaze to adhere.  Is there a better technique for glazing asparagus or other smooth vegetables in general?

Would a dip in cornstarch or other binding agent help?

Comment: Was the glaze thick and just didn't stick, or was it thin and dripping off?

Comment: @Jefromi the glaze was plenty thick; it just didn't stick.

Comment: I'm a poet and I know it!

Comment: asparagus is smooth, so it will remove, the glaze applied, before your eyes,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try peeling the asparagus. This would work better with [thicker asparagus](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/37276/whats-the-skinny-on-fat-asparagus).

Since the outer skin of asparagus is so smooth, I can see how glaze would just slip off. Peeled asparagus will have a slightly stickier surface for the glaze to hold on to. An added bonus is that some of the glaze should penetrate if the asparagus is peeled.

Be aware that peeled asparagus will cook faster than unpeeled. See also: [Should asparagus be peeled before cooking?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5147/should-asparagus-be-peeled-before-cooking?rq=1)

Comment: Great idea!  I'm sure this would help.